# Come up with vs dream up

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What's the difference between the following sentences?

> 1 They came up with a new idea.

> 2 They dreamt up with a new idea.

Comment: Don't include the preposition ***with*** after ***to dream up***. Also note that this generally a (casual / colloquial) ***disparaging*** turn of phrase (speaker doesn't think much of their new idea), whereas ***to come up with*** (also somewhat colloquial) is essentially "neutral" in and of itself (but can be used in contexts where it's *either* positive or negative). Also note that usually *They **introduced / formulated / conceived** a new idea* would be seen as positive / approving.

Comment: I think *dream up* depends on the context too, it an be used very negatively (in the sense of imagining things, or having your head in the clouds) but it can also be a more evocative phrase that suggests they've come up with something special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Dreamt up* (or "dreamed up") can imply that the idea, according to the speaker, is unrealistic -- much like a dream can be bizarre and unrealistic because it is entirely imaginary, or possibly randomly or haphazardly inspired, a revelation, without much prior effort, planning or qualification -- so like your commenter said, it may be taken as disparaging or offensive, or imply that the speaker considers the idea to be self-indulgent. And does not use "with".

Though the phrase "dreaming up new ways to [do a thing]" may not be disparaging if the context is about a person whose job it is to invent new and fantastic things, such as an artist or rocket scientist.

We also borrow the German or Yiddish expression *verkocht* when we say *cooked up* an idea (or an excuse), which is to say that it is *overcooked*, and that is also usually disparaging because nobody likes overcooked food.

Similarly, *concocted* ("concocted a way to [accomplish something]") is a variation that can imply that the idea or solution is somewhat specious; it may work or succeed but the means or methods or explanation are not convincing or may only coincidentally achieve a desired result, like to literally throw some things together (in pot, a beaker, etc.) and the product be useful, even if the mechanism of the reaction are not well understood or explained.

*Came up with* implies that the idea took work to generate, or with some amount of intent and planning, and thus it is more like an invention. It doesn't assign a positive or negative opinion; it just describes that they have generated an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Both mean the same in this context as ideas don't come without some sort of work/process/plan. 'came up with' and 'dreamt up' are a bit informal, so you can use 'brought forth,' or 'discovered,' if you want to sound more formal.

By the way, 'they dreamt up with a new idea' should be 'they dreamt up a new idea.'

Answer (score 0):

Both can mean *to invent, suggest or think of an idea*.

However, dreaming up something implies using a lot of imagination, creativity, lateral thinking. Used negatively, it could be that the idea is a bit unrealistic, silly, half-baked, or too ambitious.

And it's more natural to leave out *with*:

> They dreamt up a new idea.